# How can i check overlaps

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How can i check new records doesn't overlap with records in the database?,

I have records looks like as shown below, Before adding a new record i would like to check the new record doesn't overlap with the existing ones.

```
  ID  ProductCode ProductFrom   ProductTo  ContactID
   1   NULL         800762       800766      55
   2   NULL         800767       800789      56
   3   800790       NULL         NULL        56
   4   800791       NULL         NULL        55
   5   NULL         800792       800796      57
```

For example if a user attempts to enter 800765 i would like to display validation error since 800765 is in range between 800762 and 800766 and assigned to ID=1

I have the following code to get all records in the database

```
    var validateOverlaps= await ContactsService.GetAllContacts();// get all fields and records
```

I tried this inside my action class

```
       bool overlaps = validateOverlaps.Any(p => (p.ProductFrom <= contactToCreate.ProductCode && p.ProductTo>= contactToCreate.ProductCode));
```

If true i like to display the following validation

```
  if (overlaps)
    ModelState.AddModelError("ProductCode", "product Code range overlaps with another Product Code range.");
```

Thank you

Comment: Hi, is this in ASP.Net Core?

Comment: Your code seems correct. What error do you get?

Comment: @JacobHallgarth yes its a ASP.Net Core

Comment: @Karan i get false, when i try it with value with in range and not in the range

Comment: You can achieve this with https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html, just add validation rules to your model.